# May a person daven in a NYC subway car that has a smelly person sitting there?

Tags: halacha, tefilla

There's a saying in NYC:

"If you're pregnant or elderly, you won't get a seat. But, if you smell bad, you can get a whole subway car."

Sadly, the number of (homeless, usually) smelly people found in the NYC subway is increasing. [Shulchan Aruch O.C. 79:1](http://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayyim.79.1?lang=he&layout=lines&sidebarLang=all) states that one needs to distance himself 4 amot from excrement. 79:8 says to distance oneself from smelly garbage. Most of the smelly people on the subway smell from B.O.; possibly from urine; possibly from alcohol and possibly from cigarette or "weed" smoke. It's neither of the above. Thus, I'm not sure if these rules apply to any type of these foul odors, and I couldn't infer that these apply to even a person that smells from excrement rather than excrement itself that came out of the person. (Some of them smell **like** garbage, BTW, but I wouldn't know if they smell **from** garbage.)

In many of the NYC subway cars, you cannot pass from one car to the next; the doors are locked. Let's say someone was davening, and a smelly person entered the subway car. Can he continue davening?

Thanks to @WhyEnBe who states that 4 amot = 8-10 feet. A NYC subway car is significantly longer than this. Technically, one could be sitting more than 4 amot away from the smelly person. However, as implied by my opening paragraph, the bad smell occupies the entire car, typically. So, I'm not sure if the halacha also applies to source of the bad smell being there regardless of the distance you may be from its source.

1/8/18 - Adding to this - Typical NYC subway elevators also smell from urine. Can one daven in there?

Comment: I do not see " one needs to distance himself 4 amot from a smelly person"

Comment: @hazoriz Am I mistranslating אֲפִלּוּ אִם יֵשׁ לוֹ חֹלִי שֶׁאֵינוֹ מֵרִיחַ, צָרִיךְ לְהַרְחִיק ד' אַמּוֹת מִמָּקוֹם שֶׁיִּכְלֶה הָרֵיחַ לְמִי שֶׁמֵּרִיחַ?

Comment: Yes I think so, to me it means: even if he (the one praying) is sick and can't smell

Comment: 4 amos are about 8 feet give or take (could be low as 6 - high as 10)

Comment: IMHO, a probably crowded possibly smelly subway car isn't the most contemplative place to pray...isn't there a better place for davening in the subway system somewhere? maybe a quiet corner of a station?  Then you can just distance yourself from a stenchmeister if they approach...

Comment: Probably more of a problem of sakanas nefashos

Comment: יָצָא מִמֶּנּוּ רוּחַ מִלְּמַטָּה, אָסוּר בְּדִבְרֵי תּוֹרָה עַד שֶׁיִּכְלֶה הָרֵיחַ. וְאִם יָצָא מֵחֲבֵרוֹ, מֻתָּר בְּדִבְרֵי תּוֹרָה, מִשּׁוּם דְּאִי אֶפְשָׁר שֶׁהַתַּלְמִידִים קְצָתָם גּוֹרְסִים, וּקְצָתָם יְשֵׁנִים וּמְפִיחִים בְּתוֹךְ הַשֵּׁנָה, אֲבָל לִקְרוֹת קְרִיאַת שְׁמַע  אָסוּר, עַד שֶׁיִּכְלֶה הָרֵיחַ - from the Shulchan Aruch 79:9 - after a list of items that if they smell disqualify a place from davening. But can't find a direct mention of BO in the Poskim.

Comment: IIRC I saw R. Ovadiah write that b'diavad one may pray in the presence of B.O.

Comment: @Gary Have you ever been a NYC subway commuter? I'm not trying to argue the overall concept of your statement. However, a typical NYC subway commuter is extremely resilient and is usually able to ignore and survive these "normal" circumstances such as smelly cars. I've seen people daven, learn, recite Tehillim or whatever in conditions that the average person not used to such environments would consider perplexing, if not intolerable.

Comment: @DanF - Well, it's been about 10 years since I lived with a subway stop within easy walking distance...but I DID use the system to commute in the late 70's/early 80's, when it was at its...most interesting...

Comment: @Gary You're not missing much. DeBlazio has begun returning the subway system status to the days of the 70's.

Comment: @DanF - Hah! ...can't wait 'till the next time I visit and plop down my ...2.50 or whatever it is now...since I'm sure the last MetroCards I used have expired...always loved it when the 4 or 6 elevated trains stopped between stations for indeterminate periods...or when they chased you off the train and onto a shuttle bus...just to climb more stairs to get back on the train...

Comment: @DannySchoemann I did read the paragraph that you cited. It seems quite specific to flatulation, BTW. It seems that this was the reason as to why Chaza"l ruled that people should not wear tefillin all day long.

Comment: @user613 What "sakanat nefesh"? Not all homeless people are harmful. This tends to be an out-of-towner incorrect assumption. As a matter of fact, the majority of muggers dress well and blend into the crowd. Also, NYC subway crime  has significantly declined during the past approx. 20 years. It is beginning to rise since DeBlazio became mayor, though.

Comment: @DanF - I wonder why Deblazio doesn't just kill 2 birds with 1 stone and hand out free cheese and Section 8 vouchers at the subway entrances...?

Comment: @DanF I meant the smell is sakana nefashos. With a mayor that's against the police, of course it'll rise, although I wasn't talking about crime

Comment: @DanF - I am sure one could make a "logical leap" to smelly people, but I don't know how, so I left it as a comment. (As in: You can't daven near "invisible" flatulence.... )

Comment: @user613 "I meant the smell is sakana nefashos" - Without an emoticon, I'm assuming you're joking. The smell is not a sakanat nefesh. It's a "convenient annoyance". If you can't ignore the smell, it's annoying. If you can, it's convenient to be able to get a seat (the car is pretty much empty) esp. when u have a long commute. The person emitting the smell may have a sakanat nefesh.

Comment: @DanF ;-) is that better?

Comment: @user613 Not really. A smile still leaves the smelly person where he is. At least he's smiling; I'm not >:-[

Comment: [This response](http://dinonline.org/2012/06/10/davening-while-sweaty/) from dinonline suggests that davening next to someone who smells is forbidden.

Comment: @ezra You may have an answer if you can get a clearer definition of what the article means by " the same halacha applies to ashpa (“garbage”) that has a foul odor (79:8)". The question addresses sweat, and even that deduction is not something I see from the article. Personally, I think some of these people smell worse than garbage, but, I may not have the halachic opinion on it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this](http://din.org.il/2015/12/13/%D7%AA%D7%A4%D7%99%D7%9C%D7%94-%D7%9C%D7%99%D7%93-%D7%90%D7%93%D7%9D-%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%A9-%D7%9E%D7%9E%D7%A0%D7%95-%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%97-%D7%A8%D7%A2/) it is permissible to pray next to a person with foul body odour, assuming that the smell is sweat, rather than "something sharp":

> אם מדובר בריח של זיעה אין איסור, אלא אם כן מדובר במשהו חריף

This would presumably be based on Yerushalmi Shabbat (2:2) which states (see P'nei Moshe) that one may pray in the presence of עיטרן, a foul smelling tar, and that you shouldn't think that just because something smells bad that you must distance yourself from it.

The Hayei Adam (Vol. I: 3:12) generalises this Yerushalmi to state that (other than excrement) the only substance around which one may not pray, is that which became rotten, but something which is itself smelly is not a problem. Accordingly, if it is just the stench of sweat, it would be permissible to pray.

Nevertheless, it is good to be stringent to not pray around a distractingly bad smell (see Rambam's Hilkhot Tefilla 4:9 based on Eruvin 65a (which mentions the smell of alcohol), and the Meiri's commentary there).

Similarly, R. Adir Kohen writes [here](https://www.ykr.org.il/question/11453) that since it is permissible to pray in the presence of things which naturally smell bad, it is permissible to pray around people who reek of sweat. However, if the smell is distractingly bad, it is appropriate to be stringent to not pray there.

Regarding prayer around urine, Berakhot (25a) is explicit that prayer around urine is forbidden, although in cases of doubt whether there is urine, one may pray (see Rambam's Hilkhot Tefilla 3:15).

Significantly the Shulhan Arukh ([OH 79:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh,_Orach_Chayim.79.8?lang=he&with=all&lang2=he)) does state that it is forbidden to pray around smelly garbage.

Comment: +1. It would be useful to get a precise definition of במשהו חריף. Offhand, it sounds like this would apply to the average homeless person on the subway. The odor is so bad that they get their own subway car.

Comment: I'm sure there are varying opinions on this. +1, by the way.

Comment: Congrats on the bounty, and thanks for the thorough research. The 2nd-to-last paragraph sounds like it applies to the subway elevator. There's little mistaking that smell. A homeless person is a bit more questionable. Looks like I need to share your research with a rav - if he'd be willing to entertain this question. (They usually have more important things on their mind, and my rav hardly ever rides the subway, so he may not empathize with my *tza'ar*.)